# How to apply registry changes for any user that log into the PC

Tags: batch-file

How to set registry key for all users logging into a PC? I am trying to achieve this by running a registry update via scheduled ob whenever a user logs in but it is not updating the registry.

I am trying to setup a network path for my screen saver so it pull images from shared location. I an updating the registry to reset the folder path for all users logging into a PC . The logins used are local admin or network log ins. I wan to set the registry settings for all users and for that I trying to call a batch file which calls a .reg file. When running independently it works fine but when I am setting the the batch file as a Scheduled task using local Admin account the registry key is not edited. I am not getting any error either. Please help.

Batch file:

```
@echo off
regedit /S "Test.reg"
```

Test.reg:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Slideshow\Screensaver]
"Speed"=dword:00000000
"Shuffle"=dword:00000000
"EncryptedPIDL"="yyyyyjjjjjuyuuuuuuuuuu"
```

Comment: this sounds like a job for group policy, not something custom

Comment: I cannot do it in Group policy as it has to be executed on only one PC /Machine

Comment: Use an active directory group and add that machine to that group. Then apply the policy to that group.

Comment: heck there's even the local policy that you could use.

Comment: I removed the irrelevant tags from the question, but anyway, permissions would most like be the issue or any issue with your scheduled task setup (which would then be off topic here), I however am with @DanielA.White on this, there are policies you can use for this that is much simpler.

Comment: @DanielA.White .... I have tried Local policy . It let me set Screen saver for all Users  but does not let me specify a network path from where I can get the pictures.

Comment: I believe the root key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` points to a different path when the `reg.exe` command is executed directly or via Scheduled Tasks, because the latter runs under a different user context (unless you explicitly specify a certain user)...